# Setting up Custom Capabilities for Gravity forms

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, gravityforms

I have been using some code that has worked really well for integrating Gravity forms with s2member. I found this code snippet that works really well,

```
add_action("gform_user_registered", "add_custom_user_meta", 10, 3);
function add_custom_user_meta($user_id, $config, $entry) {

if($entry['form_id'] != 6)
    return;

wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user->add_cap ("access_s2member_ccap_test");
}
```

However the problem comes when I try to add another form to add a different capability and use more than one form.

```
add_action("gform_user_registered", "add_custom_user_meta", 10, 3);
function add_custom_user_meta($user_id, $config, $entry)

    {
    if($entry['form_id'] != 1)
        return;

    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user->add_cap ("access_s2member_ccap_SOL-free");

    if($entry['form_id'] != 5)
        return;

    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user->add_cap ("access_s2member_ccap_SOL-complete");

    }
```

I tried a few option like 'ELSE IF' but could not get it to work. Here is an example of the code I have been trying out

```
add_action("gform_user_registered", "add_custom_user_meta", 10, 3);
function add_custom_user_meta($user_id, $config, $entry)

{
if($entry['form_id'] == 1)  
{return wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user->add_cap ("access_s2member_ccap_test1");}

else if($entry['form_id'] == 2)
{wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user->add_cap ("access_s2member_ccap_test2");}

else

{return;}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.